# Having some IE8 specific loading issues on my page / Hanging at blank screen with "n items remaining" in status bar

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-8, woocommerce

So, I'm working on a new e-commerce site for my employer, and I've noticed that it displays / functions properly in every browser but IE8 (Which is rather inconveniencing, as about 80% of the office uses IE8.)

The site in question can be [found here](http://seekoften.com/eCommerce/) . When i load the page ( And more specifically, when I refresh a page ) I will sometimes have it saying "(2 items remaining) Waiting for..." and then it just hangs at a blank screen, until I type in a different URL or navigate to a different page.

Can somebody please offer me some insight as to why this might be happening, and what kind of things I can do to regulate it.

Answer (score 0):

I used [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/) to test this and I didn't have a problem at all. This could very well be a JavaScript issue.

Try minimizing & concatenating your JS & CSS files. You can also create image sprites instead of loading lots of small images. After all that IE will have less files to download and they'll all be smaller so that should help.

Also, I see you're using WordPress which is a little harder to set up by try loading your JS at the bottom of the page. That way IE doesn't get hung up on a JS file at the top.

Comment: I have since switched themes on the site, it was the theme "Mystile" giving me errors. Also, for what it's worth, It was working fine for me on BrowserStack too, and on my work comp Which is Win7 IE10, by using developer tools for different ver. But on an actual installation of IE8 ( Which I test using virtualBox on my Mac ),which most of the people at my office use, it has that loading issue and has given me an error akin to 

Message:'JSON' is undefined
Line:1
Char: 353
Code:0
URL:http://seekoften.com/eCommerce/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/cart-fragments.min.js?ver=2.0.1

Comment: Bizarre that it's only certain versions of IE8... Maybe a configuration setting somewhere? Compatibility mode?

Comment: That's what I thought, and I've played with all those settings to no avail. I've basically chosen another theme that still displays kinda funky in IE8 (surprise). But loads / functions a lot smoother, so I'll just make IE specific edits to address the odd display of it.

Thanks anyways for your help man, Cheers.